# Visual Studio 2010: C++: Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm having these 2 errors, while compiling this C++ code with Visual Studio 2010 professional:

```
Principal.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: enum TP1::Couleur __thiscall TP1::Labyrinthe::trouveGagnant(void)" (?trouveGagnant@Labyrinthe@TP1@@QAE?AW4Couleur@2@XZ)

Principal.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall TP1::Labyrinthe::solutionner(enum TP1::Couleur)" (?solutionner@Labyrinthe@TP1@@QAEHW4Couleur@2@@Z)
```

Both the .cpp and the .h files are below:

```
// principal.cpp

\#include "Labyrinthe.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace TP1;

int main()
{
        try
        {
                Labyrinthe lab;

                ifstream entree("FichiersLabyrinthe/rouge.txt");

                if (!entree)
                {
                        cout << "Fichier rouge introuvable.\n";
                        return 1;
                }

                lab.chargeLabyrinthe(Rouge, entree);
                cout << "\nLabyrinthe rouge charg�.\n";
                entree.close();

                entree.open("FichiersLabyrinthe/vert.txt", ios::in);
                if (!entree)
                {
                        cout << "Fichier vert introuvable.\n";
                        return 1;
                }

                lab.chargeLabyrinthe(Vert, entree);
                cout << "\nLabyrinthe vert charg�.\n";
                entree.close();

                entree.open("FichiersLabyrinthe/bleu.txt", ios::in);
                if (!entree)
                {
                        cout << "Fichier bleu introuvable.\n";
                        return 1;
                }

                lab.chargeLabyrinthe(Bleu, entree);
                cout << "\nLabyrinthe bleu charg�.\n";
                entree.close();

                entree.open("FichiersLabyrinthe/jaune.txt", ios::in);
                if (!entree)
                {
                        cout << "Fichier jaune introuvable.\n\n";
                        return 1;
                }

                lab.chargeLabyrinthe(Jaune, entree);
                cout << "\nLabyrinthe jaune charg�.\n";
                entree.close();

                cout << "\nLe joueur rouge peut solutionner le labyrinthe en "
                                << lab.solutionner(Rouge) << " d�placements.\n";
                cout << "\nLe joueur vert peut solutionner le labyrinthe en "
                                << lab.solutionner(Vert) << " d�placements.\n";
                cout << "\nLe joueur bleu peut solutionner le labyrinthe en "
                                << lab.solutionner(Bleu) << " d�placements.\n";
                cout << "\nLe joueur jaune peut solutionner le labyrinthe en "
                                << lab.solutionner(Jaune) << " d�placements.\n";

                Couleur LeGagnant = lab.trouveGagnant();
                switch (LeGagnant)
                {
                case 0:
                        cout << endl << "Le joureur gagnant: Rouge" << endl << endl;
                        break;
                case 1:
                        cout << endl << "Le joureur gagnant: Vert" << endl << endl;
                        break;
                case 2:
                        cout << endl << "Le joureur gagnant: Bleu" << endl << endl;
                        break;
                case 3:
                        cout << endl << "Le joureur gagnant: Jaune" << endl << endl;
                        break;
                default:
                        cout << endl << "Le joureur gagnant: aucun!!" << endl << endl;
                        break;
                }
        } catch (exception & e)
        {
                cerr << e.what() << endl;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

//================================================ Labyrinthe.h

```
#ifndef LABYRINTHE_H_
#define LABYRINTHE_H_

#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <sstream> 
#include <string>

#include "Chemin.h"
#include "Porte.h"
#include "Piece.h"
#include "FilePieces.h"

#pragma warning( disable : 4290 )

namespace TP1
{


class Labyrinthe
{
public:

        Labyrinthe();
        virtual ~Labyrinthe();
        Labyrinthe(const Labyrinthe&);

        const Labyrinthe& operator =(const Labyrinthe& source) throw (std::bad_alloc);

        void chargeLabyrinthe(Couleur couleur, std::ifstream &entree);

        void ajoutePieceLabyrinthe(Piece &p) throw (std::bad_alloc);

        int solutionner(Couleur joueur);

        Couleur trouveGagnant();

        Chemin cheminLabyrinthe(Couleur joueur);

private:

        void ajoutePassage(Couleur couleur, int i1, int j1, int i2, int j2);

        void placeDepart(std::string& nom) throw (std::logic_error);

        void placeArrivee(std::string& nom) throw (std::logic_error);


        class NoeudListePieces 
        public:

                Piece piece;

                NoeudListePieces *suivant;
        };

        NoeudListePieces *trouvePiece(std::string &nom) const
                        throw (std::invalid_argument, std::logic_error);
        NoeudListePieces *dernier;

        Piece *depart, *arrivee;

        int compteurLab;

};

}

#endif /* LABYRINTHE_H_ */
```

Anyone can help me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have not given the code (definition for) methods `Labyrinthe::trouveGagnant` and `Labyrinthe::solutionner`. The compiler is complaining that you are calling two functions that have not been defined anywhere, so it's not possible to produce code for it.

Did you forget to include `Labyrinthe.cpp` in your project?

Answer (score 2):

You only supplied code for `Labyrinthe.h` and `principal.cpp`.

The functions declared in Labyrinthe.h are not defined anywhere. Most likely, their definition resides in `Labyrinthe.cpp`. Make sure you compile that file as well.

In general, the compiler only looks for symbol declarations. That is because definitions can reside in a separate module. When you link against a library, you find the definition there. In your case, the definition resides in the same module, so you need the implementation to be compiled (the part in the cpp file).